# Rails 3 Sorting Submissions by most recently popular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-order-by

I have a site that has user submissions that users can vote on.  I want to be able to organize these submissions on my homepage in a variety of fashions, but the most complex one is the "Currently Popular". I assume the best way to go about this is named scopes, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

Each submission has the attributes: `votes_up:integer`, and `votes_down:integer`

I think the best way to do this will be to find the ratio of `votes_up / (votes_up + votes_down)`, all within the last day. I additionally have a Votes model that has: `submission_id, vote_type ("up" or "down"), and user_id`. Obviously both submissions and votes have `created_at:datetimes` I think it would be better if it returned results that had a large quantity of votes in the last 1 day, rather than submissions that are from the last 1 day (that way submissions that take time to gather steam can still qualify)

How would I structure a query that will return submissions in this order with the date limitations?

Does this make sense?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular with whom? With a / a + b you'll get a lot of noise when you have just a handful of votes, and when you have a controversial subject the votes won't at all reflect the quality of the material. People take sides and engage in politics, and people with bad opinions will tend to vote way too much.

The theoretically ideal way to deal with this is to highlight content that someone the user usually agrees with endorses and hide the stuff from people who they disagree with. A special list can have the most controversial subjects. This approach can be resource intensive, and I don't know how well Ruby on Rails does database optimization.

Comment: interesting. how would you go about doing this from a framework agnostic perspective? Regardless of Rails? Rails can do any queries you can do in SQL.

Comment: I think the naive, unoptimized way would be to give each user a table with two int columns. One column has the user_id of their friend/foe and the other has the goodness value. It's a one-to-one relation of only two values, so it should be easy to think about and compute. Each article stores the user_id of their voters in two columns, vote up and vote down, and the display function checks these against the user's two columns to add up the goodness values to a final score of plus's and and minuses. -- I might discover a problem with this after I've had my coffee, be warned. :o)

Comment: interesting! i like this a lot. I think it will be very computationally straining on the server (at least for someone like me who is inexperienced in writing algorithms) to calculate the 'goodness' value.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest using [vote_fu](https://github.com/peteonrails/vote_fu) and seeing if recent karma satisfies your need?

Comment: i've used vote_fu before but this time I built a more custom system. However I don't know anything about recent_karma. I believe the karma in vote_fu is related to a voter, not to the voteable.